# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'off') when calling removeLayer() in a for loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Say I have the following code:

```
var streets = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

var yearLayers = {};
yearLayers['1877'] = L.tileLayer('https://terrafrost.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/maps/austin/v2/1877/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
  
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [30.267222, -97.743056],
    zoom: 13,
  layers: [streets]
});

layerControl = L.control.layers().addTo(map);
layerControl.addBaseLayer(streets, 'Streets');
layerControl.addOverlay(yearLayers['1877'], '1877');

layerControl.removeLayer(yearLayers['1877']);

/*
var years = ['1877'];
for (var i = 0; i < years; i++) {
    year = years[i];
    layerControl.removeLayer(yearLayers[year]);
}
*/
```

That code runs without issue but, if I comment out the `layerControl.removeLayer(yearLayers['1877']);` and uncomment out the for loop I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'off')
    at i.removeLayer (Control.Layers.js:142:9)
    at whatever:x:y
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7rkzjLp/2/ shows what I mean. Well, more specifically, that link shows the error.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7rkzjLp/1/ shows it code without the for loop running without issue.

So why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: your loop is iterating over the array itself rather than the array.length. Fix your loop 
`for (var i = 0; i < years; i++) {` it should look like this instead `for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {`

Comment: Also try and avoid implicit globals -> `year = years[i];`  and I would avoid using `var`, instead use `const` & `let`.